# Ember.js Appropriately reference property of unrelated item

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Assuming an ember.js router application with an application controller, application view, a view type that I plug and play with, and an unrelated controller that handles external data. How can that third view have a computed property from the unrelated controller, what do I put into the `.property()` elipses so that it gets notified of changes?

e.g.

```
App.ExternalDataController = Em.Controller.extend
    stellarProperty: 'super value' #I want OtherView to have a computer property referencing this

App.ApplicationController = Em.ArrayController.extend
    content: [] #Assume a bunch of values of some kind here

App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend
    templateName: 'app-view'

App.OtherView = Em.View.extend
    templateName: 'other-view'
    someComputedProperty: (->
        App.router.externalDataController.get('stellarProperty') + ' flying pigs'
    ).property() #What do I put in that property elipses?
```

templates

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
   <div>
       {{#each content}}
           {{name}} -- {{view App.OtherView}}
       {{/each}}
   </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="other-view">
   <span>Irate goats and {{view.someComputedProperty}}</span>
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you should make the property you need available through the view's controller.

In your example, because `OtherView` is nested in the `ApplicationView`'s template, it will have a `controller` property that is set to `ApplicationController`. In your router, you can call `router.applicationController.connectControllers('externalData')`. That will set an `externalDataController` property on `applicationController`. Then you can expose the property you need:

```
App.ApplicationController = Em.ArrayController.extend
  content: [] #Assume a bunch of values of some kind here
  externalDataController: null # set via connectControllers call in router
  stellarPropertyBinding: Em.Binding.oneWay('externalDataController.stellarProperty')
```

And `OtherView` becomes:

```
App.OtherView = Em.View.extend
  templateName: 'other-view'
  someComputedProperty: (->
    @get('controller.stellarProperty') + ' flying pigs'
  ).property('controller.stellarProperty')
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: `router.applicationController.connectControllers('externalData')` is the ticket, Thanks!